# comboBox C# Winform

Tags: c#, combobox

I am having a problem. I have a comboBox in that when I am entering

`BlowMolding` by coding `comboSub1.Text = "BlowMolding"`.
It is automatically picking a value from list `Blowmolding`.
I know it is due to the fact that values are same except the case of "M" 
and "m".
But in my application it creates problem.
So, Please tell me how to stop combo from picking the value 
automatically and stick to the value I am assigning to it. Even if only 
the case is changed.

Comment: Show your code, it will be helpful.

Comment: I'm not clear on what your question is. Rephrase it and add some code and maybe someone will be able to help

Comment: more information would be helpful, but if I understand you correctly, you should use selectedIndex vs trying to set the Text value. So if BlowMolding is at index[0] and Blowmolding is at index[1] then set it to 0 as selected index.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx

side note: if this is in fact your solution, let me suggest to in general use indexes vs values, especially when working with 'lookup' data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
comboSub1.SelectedIndex = comboSub1.Items.IndexOf("BlowMolding");
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, you are trying to set some value as text of your comboBox, and you also want that the `text` property should be set to whatever value you set explicitly.

If this the case then you should set the `DropDownStyle` property of your combo box to `DropDown` instead of `DropDownList`, which prevents you from setting value apart from what is have already in list.

```
this.comboBox1.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
```

you may also set this value via prperties window.